# Display data from combobox to a datagridview

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, combobox

I am trying to get data  from a combo Box into a datagrindview but when I run the program it shows the datagrindview blank! any suggestions ?
Thank you

```html
private void fillCombo()
         {
                 string query = "select DISTINCT FirstName,LastName from ActivityDataView";
                 myConnection.Open();
                 myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
                 myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
                
                 SqlDataReader dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            
            while (dr.Read())
                 {
                     string name = String.Format("{0} {1} ",  dr["LastName"], dr["FirstName"]);
                     comboBox1.Items.Add(name);      
                }
            dr.Close();
          
     
            myConnection.Close();

        }
```

here is the funcion for the combobox

```
         private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string query = "select * from ActivityDataView where LastName='" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "'";

            myConnection.Open();
                 myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

               myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);  
           dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0];

             myConnection.Close();

        }
```

Comment: WinForms? WebForms? Need to be more specific.

Comment: It's WinForm!!!

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47628723/edit) your question; do not change your question in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format clearly states that you are selecting the lastname as well as the first name into your combobox:

```
string name = String.Format("{0} {1} ",  dr["LastName"], dr["FirstName"]);
```

but when you fetch data for your `DataGridView` you try to compare this entire string with the `LastName` row.

To solve this you could split the combobox string and get only the last name

```
string lastName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
                .Split(new string[] { " "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First();
```